https not being forced after modifying apache configuration for reverse proxy
I'm running an Apache/Cpanel server and wrote an Apache host domain include config file to point a one of my domain names to a port number for a Next.js app I created.
The although it partially works. The problem i'm encountering is that it's not forcing https in a lot of instances, and instead pulling an apache error page.
Here is the script I have for it:
ServerAdmin josh@howard.codes
    ServerName www.howard.codes

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>

This is mainly happening in Firefox. Is my include.conf files incorrect?

I was able to solve my own problem by removing the www from the ServerName. This results in the url being forwarded to a secure connection on the desired port with no issues.
